# How to set alarm in metric filter using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, alarm

**How to create alarm for metric filter and connect SNS topic.**

My task is:

1. Create SNS topic and email subscription
2. Create CloudWatch log group
3. Create metric filter for that CloudWatch log group and create alarm and connect SNS topic

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
#Parameters:
 #EmailAddress:
  #Type: String
  #Description: The email address to use for alarm notifications.

Resources:
 # Create SNS and email subscription
 MySNSTopic:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  Properties:
    Subscription:
    - Endpoint: "abcd@abc.com"
      Protocol: email
   
 # Create CloudWatch log group
 snstopic: 
  Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
  DependsOn: MySNSTopic
  Properties: 
    RetentionInDays: 7
  
 # Create metric filter
 UnauthorizedApiCalls: 
  Type: AWS::Logs::MetricFilter
  DependsOn: snstopic
  Properties: 
    LogGroupName: 
      Ref: "snstopic"
    FilterPattern: '{($.errorCode="*UnauthorizedOperation") || ($.errorCode="AccessDenied*")}'
    MetricTransformations: 
      - MetricValue: "1"
        MetricNamespace: "unauthorized-api-calls"
        MetricName: "LogMetrics"
  
 # Create alarm
 UnauthorizedApiCallsAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  DependsOn: UnauthorizedApiCalls
  Properties:
    AlarmName: UnauthorizedApiCallsAlarm
    AlarmActions: !Ref snstopic
    MetricName: UnauthorizedApiCalls
    Namespace: LogMetrics
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
    EvaluationPeriods: '1'
    Period: '5'
    Statistic: Sum
    Threshold: '1'
    TreatMissingData: breaching
```

Comment: Did you try this cfn yaml? And what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: not create alarm in cloudwatch log group.

Comment: I think my "create alarm" yaml code is wrong. Can you fix this?

Comment: Why do you think its wrong? What exactly is happening? Any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html), the type of `AlarmActions` is `List of String`.

```yaml
# Create alarm
UnauthorizedApiCallsAlarm:
 Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
 DependsOn: UnauthorizedApiCalls
 Properties:
   AlarmName: UnauthorizedApiCallsAlarm
   AlarmActions: 
   - !Ref snstopic
   MetricName: UnauthorizedApiCalls
   Namespace: LogMetrics
   ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
   EvaluationPeriods: '1'
   Period: '5'
   Statistic: Sum
   Threshold: '1'
   TreatMissingData: breaching
```

Comment: Comes this "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE". Cannot create the stack. What should I do?

Comment: 1)create SNS topic and email subscription
2)create cloudwatch log group
3)create metric filter for that cloudwatch log group and create alarm and connect sns topic.       These are my main requirements.

Comment: What is the error messages for ROLLBACK_COMPLETE? Please provide all error messages.